# C++ Class Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to programming in C++ and I have encountered a problem that I cannot seem to solve when enforcing separate compilation. I am trying to specialize my class `tokenize` to add a dtor for a specific type (`istream`). I have the following:

```
#ifndef __TOKENIZER_H__
#define __TOKENIZER_H__

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class base {
  // ... some methods/member variables.
};

template <class T>
class tokenizer : public base<T> {
  public:
    tokenizer(T &in);
};

template <>
class tokenizer<std::ifstream> : public base<std::ifstream> {
  public:
    tokenizer(std::ifstream &in);
    ~tokenizer();
};

#endif
```

... and:

```
#include "tokenizer.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using std::ifstream;
using std::istream;
using std::string;

// [BASE]

// ... code for those functions.

// [TOKENIZER]

// See header file.
template <class T>
tokenizer<T>::tokenizer(T &in) : base<T>(in) { }

// See header file.
template <>
tokenizer<ifstream>::tokenizer(ifstream &in) : base<ifstream>(in) { }

// See header file.
template <>
tokenizer<ifstream>::~tokenizer() {
  delete &(base<ifstream>::in);
}

// Intantiating template classes (separate compilation).
template class base<std::ifstream>;
template class base<std::istream>;
template class tokenizer<std::ifstream>;
template class tokenizer<std::istream>;
```

... however I get the following error:

```
tokenizer.cc:62: error: template-id ‘tokenizer<>’ for ‘tokenizer<std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::tokenizer(std::ifstream&)’ does not match any template declaration
tokenizer.cc:66: error: template-id ‘tokenizer<>’ for ‘tokenizer<std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::~tokenizer()’ does not match any template declaration
```

I am compiling with g++. If someone can kindly point out what I am missing and a possible explanation then that would be fantastic. I am confused how templates work with separate compilation (defns/decl separated).

Comment: "how templates work with separate compilation" — they pretty much don't, at all. "tokenizer.cc:62" — where is line 62?

Comment: IIRC the moment you declare an explicit specialization of the class template `tokenizer`, it becomes like a "normal class". Leave out the `template<>` for the ctor and dtor definitions.

Comment: [temp.expl.spec]/5 "Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax."

Comment: Also, `delete &(base<ifstream>::in);` probably isn't going to work.

Comment: The identifier `__TOKENIZER_H__` is reserved for the C++ compiler and its standard library: any identifer containing two consecutive underscored is reserved.

Comment: @DyP, removing `template <>` solved the compile error, can you construct an answer below so I can mark it as 'solved'? Much appreciated.

Comment: @n.m., if I am using `ifstream` I am invoking it as: `tokenizer t(*(new ifstream("test.txt")))`. It's necessary for the clean up.

Comment: I'm not sure how the explicit instantiations help you. They're inside the .cc file, therefore they're not seen in any other TU. `tokenizer<std::ifstream>` is never instantiated implicitly as it is explicitly specialized; all other specializations will be instantiated in every TU as it stands.

Comment: You should change the `tokenizer<std::ifstream>` ctor to require an r-value reference to signify that `tokenizer<std::ifstream>` has resource ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[temp.expl.spec]/5 states:

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax. The same is true when defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class. However, `template<>` is used in
>   defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class template that is specialized as a class template.

It also provides the following example (I'll only quote some excerpts):

> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>     template<class U> struct C { };
> };
>
> template<> struct A<int> {
>     void f(int);
> };
>
> // template<> not used for a member of an
> // explicitly specialized class template
> void A<int>::f(int) { /∗ ... ∗/ }
>
> template<> template<class U> struct A<char>::C {
>     void f();
> };
> // template<> is used when defining a member of an explicitly
> // specialized member class template specialized as a class template
> template<>
> template<class U> void A<char>::C<U>::f() { /∗ ... ∗/ }
> ```

As far as I know, once you've explicit specialized a class template, you've created a "normal class". It's obviously not a template any more (you cannot create classes from the specialization), but a type with some `<..>` in its name.

In your case, that just means leave out the `template<>` before

> ```
> // See header file.
> //template <>
> tokenizer<ifstream>::tokenizer(ifstream &in) : base<ifstream>(in) { }
>
> // See header file.
> //template <>
> tokenizer<ifstream>::~tokenizer() {
>   delete &(base<ifstream>::in);
> }
> ```

---

With regard to your request on clarification of the combination of separate compilation with templates:

When you use a class template to create an object (e.g. `std::vector<int> v`) or call a function template (e.g. `std::sort(begin(v), end(v))`), you're dealing with *specializations* of the templates. `std::vector<int>` is a specialization of the class template `std::vector`.

When a specialization is required in a TU, it might be necessary to produce it from the class template. This is called *instantiation*. An explicitly specialized template won't be instantiated implicitly (it already *is* specialized). That is, your specialization `tokenizer<ifstream>` doesn't have to be instantiated in any TU.

Templates itself don't work with separate compilation for these reasons. However, you can use explicit instantiations and explicit specializations to provide the benefits of separate compilation for *specializations* of templates. For example:

[header.hpp]

```
template<class T> void foo(T);
extern template void foo<int>(int);
```

[impl.cpp]

```
#include "header.hpp"

template<class T> void foo(T) { return T{} };

template void foo<int>(int); // force instantiation
```

[main.cpp]

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo<int>(42); // no instantiation will occur
}
```

In main.cpp we couldn't instantiate the definition of `foo`, as the definition is not available. We could instantiate the declaration. There's also an explicit instantiation declaration, which prevents any implicit instantiation. In another TU (impl.cpp), we did instantiate `foo<int>` via an explicit instantiation *definition*. This requires the definition of `f` to exist and instantiates the definition. The rest is similar to normal functions: We have two declarations and one definition.

Similarly, for class templates: If the definition of a class is required in a TU, we need to either instantiate the template or we need to have an explicit specialization (an explicit instantiation definition is not possible here AFAIK). This is exactly the OP's example.

If the definition of the class is *not* required, we can use something similar to the PIMPL idiom:

[header.hpp]

```
template<class T>
class foobar;

struct s
{
    foobar<int>* p;
    void f();
}
```

[impl.cpp]

```
#include "header.hpp"

template<class T> class foobar { int i; }

void s::f() { p = new foobar{42}; }
```

[main.cpp]

```
int main()
{
    s obj;
    obj.f();
}
```